# Fit Default D3 Projection to Daily Kos Congressional District Hexmap

Tags: d3.js, gis, topojson

The Daily Kos has a unique "Congressional District Hexmap - CDs - Congressional Districts (50 states) only" shapefile - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LrBXlqrtSZwyYOkpEEXFwQggvtR0bHHTxs9kq4kjOjw/edit#gid=1250379179 - which is perfect for our use case. But I'm running into an issue fitting it to the container size of our design. Traditionally, I take a TopoJSON file, i.e. US States, project it with an Albers USA projection (or other) and then use the container width and height to calculate the optimal `path` for the shapes - see below.

In this "Congressional District Hexmap" case, I believe the shapefile is already projected and therefore when I apply an Albers or Mercator projection it distorts its look and feel.

Therefore I was wondering if there is a `null` or default projection that will still allow me to use the `fitSize()` helper function to scale the shapes to the container?

[image: An Albers US projection applied to a hex congressional district map]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Therefore I was wondering if there is a null or default projection that will still allow me to use the fitSize() helper function to scale the shapes to the container?

Passing `null` to `path.projection()` won't help you; however, `d3.geoIdentity` will. By default it is the same as a null projection in the sense it takes input coordinates and outputs them with no transform or projection. However, it does offer access to a number of useful methods, such as `scale` and `translate`, as well as `fitSize`, `fitExtent`, etc (these just set scale and translate afterall). The docs have a bit more info [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#geoIdentity).

However, depending on your data source, you may need to reflect the y coordinates as geographic y values increase as one moves north (generally), while SVG/Canvas y values increase as one moves down (south, often).

So you could use:

```
var projection = d3.geoIdentity()
                   .reflectY(true) // if needed.
                   .fitSize([width,height],geoJsonObject)
```

With your path generator.